# bools for tables + search

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, crud

Attempting to database driven website for video rentals

So I have two tables in my database (movie, and rental), 
I have a column set in each table 'OnHire' which has the data value of 'bit'
with NULL values selected.

So I have all the CRUD features working but...

When the user creates a new rental record in the rental table and turns 'OnHire' to true
I am trying to use a bool which will then turn the 'OnHire' in movies to true.

Allowing the user to know by looking at the movies table whether it is on hire or not
it is telling me i cant convert a type bool? to bool, a conversion exists(are you missing a cat)?

```
HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Rental rentals)
    {
        try
        {
            // TODO: Add insert logic here
            _entities.AddToRentals(rentals);
            _entities.SaveChanges();

            Movie mov = new Movie();

            if (rentals.OnHire)
            {
                mov.OnHire = true;
            }
            else
            {
                mov.OnHire = false;
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Then I am probably pushing my luck here but if that is successfull I was going to do the opposite and throw an error message if the user tries to hire out a video already on hire

```
            if (mov.OnHire)
            {
                //error message
            }
```

Any suggestions?

Also on completion of the CRUD for database I was looking to implement a search feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use rentals.OnHire == true instead of rentals.OnHire.

```
if (rentals.OnHire == true)
{
    mov.OnHire = true;
}
else
{
    mov.OnHire = false;
}
```